# wininet api-sending files to a http web service

Tags: winapi, c++11, wininet

I have a wininet c++ client in native code that has to send authentication data as query string followed by  files asynchronously to a http web service...

1.what are the mandatory steps in forming the http request(like flags to be set) for this context?

2.what are the options for sending a SOAP message with mfc/win32 environment?

3.is SOAP the only way to communicate with webservices or with only xml web services? a http web service can accept files with traditional calls like Httpsendrequest?

this is the soap string I have in mind.

```
      constWCHAR* g_lpszSOAPRequest =
       "<soap:Envelope "
         xmlns:n='urn:xmethods-Temperature' "
        ........................................................             ..........
                ................................................

      ...<soap:Body>
      <n:UploadFile>
    <n:FileName>string</FileName>
    <n:FileData>base64Binary</FileData>
     <n:UploadFile>
    </soap:Body>
```

I am hoping that I can replace classname,methodname,params in the above string and get it to work with most web services? is it a right assumption?

Answer (score 0):

ATL Server has client functions for using soap. Maybe this article helps as an [introduction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc301865.aspx).

You find more code samples for ATL-Server and Soap. I.e. [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/complus/soap/article.php/c3945/SOAP-Client-Using-Visual-C.htm).

ATL server is now a part of [Codeplex](http://atlserver.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Personally I would go for the newer API's. My client has a PC monitoring application of which http upload is basically one class. here they are specifying wininet as the requirement.for the simple scenario we do a upload/download and get a response, would not  a simple soap request message suffice?

the client wants the class to e generic enough to work with various upload/download web services.